# React Fullcalendar error null reading getUTCFullYear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, fullcalendar

I am really fresh to react, then i have problem when implement react full calendar. I have state like this:

```
  const [dateEvent, setDateEvent] = useState("");
```

And i have function to check the id from another component, since this still using dummy data. Below the code.

```
function getStartDate() {
    INITIAL_EVENTS.filter((obj) => {
      if (obj.eventId == eventId) {
        let currentDate = obj.startEvent;
        setDateEvent(currentDate);
        console.log(currentDate);
      }
    });
  }
```

I would set 'initialDate' on react full calendar using state, each time get new ID from other component with another it will set 'initialdate', however it always error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getUTCFullYear')"

For example my current dummy data like below:

```
 {
    id: "2",
    eventId: "2",
    title: "Training Security Network Part 3",
    startEvent: "2023-08-13T08:00:00",
    endEvent: "2023-08-13T12:00:00",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    eventId: "3",
    title: "Training Security Network Part 4",
    startEvent: "2023-08-10T08:00:00",
    endEvent: "2023-08-10T12:00:00",
  },
```

Below my initialize of fullcalendar

```
<FullCalendar
            plugins={[
              dayGridPlugin,
              timeGridPlugin,
              interactionPlugin,
              listPlugin,
            ]}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: "prev,next",
              center: "title",
              right: "timeGridDay,listDay",
   }}
  initialView="timeGridDay"
  editable={true}
  selectable={true}
  selectMirror={true}
  dayMaxEvents={true}
  weekends={weekendsVisible}
  select={handleClickDate}
  initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS}
  initialDate={dateEvent}
  eventClick={handleEventClick}
  eventsSet={handleEvents}
   />
```

Please enlighten me about this

Comment: Are you adding a new calendar event in the calendar state after a new event id is provided by the other component?

Comment: I would like to do that, so each id let say have 2 event on specific date, user will can add event on that date, but i cannot reach it now, because that error

Comment: the id used to load data, from dummy data which contain start and end date of an event

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have put the project on this: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-platform-mvdtrn?file=/src/App.js
I am sorry that it is not full complete my project

Comment: Does [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-sun-rvc9q8?file=/src/App.js) solve your issue?